# webpack and jquery-minicolors : TypeError: element.minicolors is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, webpack

I need to use the jquery-minicolors NPM package in my Angular app using webpack.

I installed it with `yarn add jquery-minicolors` and I've also added the `import 'jquery-minicolors'` in my app but I have the following error :

```
TypeError: element.minicolors is not a function
    at initMinicolors (https://localhost/packs/application-4e03b2893762c0222662.js:244728:19)
    at Object.link (https://localhost/packs/application-4e03b2893762c0222662.js:244751:9)
    ...
```

Looking a bit further into the source code I saw the following :

```
(function (factory) {
  if(typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
    // AMD. Register as an anonymous module.
    define(['jquery'], factory);
  } else if(typeof exports === 'object') {
    // Node/CommonJS
    module.exports = factory(require('jquery'));
  } else {
    // Browser globals
    factory(jQuery);
  }
}(function ($) {
  ...
```

So I'm guessing that webpack doesn't import it correctly.

I have updated my webpack config adding this :

```
environment.plugins.append('Provide', new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
  $: 'jquery',
  jQuery: 'jquery'
}))

environment.loaders.append('jquery-minicolors', {
  test: require.resolve('jquery-minicolors'),
  loader: 'imports-loader?this=>window,define=>false,$=jquery'
})
```

But I still have the JS error.

Can you please help me on this so that it loads fine?